# Evaluate the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(t²+2t)/2}e^{-i\omega t}dt$

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

I have this integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(t²+2t)/2}e^{-i\omega t}dt$$ I don't know how to solve it, but I have tried, like this:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{(-(t²+2t)/2)+(-i\omega t)}dt $$ Then I substitute $$ u = \frac{t²-2t}{2}-i\omega t = \frac{1}{2}t²-t-i\omega t\\du = t-1-i\omega dt \\ dt = \frac{1}{t-1-i \omega}$$

I'm stuck here. I don't think that there should be a t left in the last formula, but I don't know how to get rid of it. If I put this with the integral I still have an annoying t to handle...

How do I get from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because

$$(t²+2t)/2+i\omega t=t^2+2t\left(\frac{1}{2}(1+i\omega)\right)=t^2+2tu=(t+u)^2-u^2$$
$$u=(1/2)(1+i \omega)$$
We have

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp((-(t²+2t)/2)+(-i\omega t))dt=\exp(u^2)\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(t+u)^2}dt=\exp(u^2)\sqrt{\pi}$$
$$=\exp(-(iu)^2)\sqrt{\pi}=\sqrt{\pi}\exp(-(1/4)(-i+ \omega)^2)$$

Comment: Could you please explain how you calculate u, because I don't see how it could be $(1/2)(1-i\omega)$

Comment: @theva. You complete the square in the exponential to get $u=(1/2)(1+i\omega)$

Comment: @theva. I added a few steps and see if it helps.